# Django rest framework - parsing result into tsv

Tags: django, rest, django-views, django-rest-framework

```
class TestAPI(APIView):   
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        # Here, I process the request in SomeClass method
        # 'some_result' is a tuple in the format below
        some_result = SomeClass.some_method(request)
        response = Response(some_result, status=status.HTTP_200_OK, headers=None)
        return response
```

FYI, `'some_result'` contains:

```
(u'text1', [('dataA1', 'dataA2', 'dataA3'), ('dataB1', 'dataB2', 'dataB3')], 'text2')
```

So my question is, is it possible to parse this tuple (above) so I could return a tsv like this:

```
dataA1 dataA2 dataA3
dataB1 dataB2 dataB3
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the 'tsv'? What's a prototype of the Response() function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation on implementing a custom renderer.

http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers.html#custom-renderers

The custom renderer will look something like this...

```
class TSVRenderer(renderers.BaseRenderer):
    media_type = 'text/tsv'
    format = 'tsv'

    def render(self, data, media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
        return ...  # TODO: Convert you incoming data representation into a TSV string
```

You can then add your renderer to the view by setting the `renderer_classes` attribute...

```
class TestAPI(APIView):
    renderer_classes = [TSVRenderer]
    ...
```